# Grub keyboard doesn't work using fast boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub, bios

I am running Gigbyte Z97-HD3 mobo and Linux Mint 19.3. I also have another HD running windows 10.

I usually use the grub boot menu to select my OS at start up.

Today I decided to check what fast boot does. So I enabled it in "ultra" mode. I assumed I wouldn't be able to get into my BIOS at start up, but I thought I would still be able to use grub.

The grub boot menu does show at every boot, but the keyboard is not working. Because of this, I can no longer select the windows 10 OS.

Is there a way I can enable the keyboard in grub while still using fast boot. If not, how do I access the bios to turn it off?

Comment: Most systems also have UEFI setting to turn on or allow USB or specific settings for USB keyboard & mouse. Both Windows & Linux use their own drivers once booted, but grub relies on the UEFI/BIOS for keyboard. My Asus Z97 has a setting to give me 3 sec to press a key, so I use that and also set grub to 3 sec. With my SSD that is a lot of my total boot time, but gives me a chance to press a key to get into system or grub menu. Reboot into UEFI:
`sudo systemctl reboot --firmware` or
`sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`

Comment: "systemctl reboot --firmware-setup" should've been selected as the correct answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to remove the CMOS battery.